# Using Python environments in VS Code outside of python files

Tags: virtualenv, vscode-extensions, vscode-python

The Python vscode extension allows us to select venv as well as python interpreters.
I seems like the Python extension is only started when opening a .py file. So before that, it is not possible to use it to switch env.
I would like to create a vscode extension allowing me to do the same for other types of files. (so without the need of opening a .py file)
Is this possible? How should it be done?

Thx a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I was looking for is adding

```
"extensionDependencies": [
    "ms-python.python"
],
```

in the package.json of my extension

Answer (score 0):

If you read the `activationEvents` section, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/package.json#L59 you know that a lot of things can trigger the extension to load, such as adding certain files to the workspace, `setup.py` for example.